# rotateY or rotateX just make my picture smaller when they rotate it

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a product div and whenever I hover over it, it rotated and shows the other side, it works and all but the thing is it becomes smaller, here's an idea of what it looks like [here](https://gyazo.com/e07b98befd39a683c25ec55cd2d96047).

```css
.product {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.1, -.60, .50, 1.2);
  perspective: 700px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.inner img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
}
.product:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.product:hover .side-b {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: block;
}
.product:hover .side-a {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.product-desc {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  /* For centering text inside .photo-overlay */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="product">
    <div style="height: 7px;visibility: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      <img class="side-a" src="../images/test.jpg" alt="International Space Station">
      <div class="product-desc side-b">
        <h3>hi</h3>
        <a href="#" class="button">buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Converted to snippet, can you make it run properly?

Comment: Do you want me to give you a JFiddle link for it to be easier to see?

Comment: Yeah, you should always include a working example in your question.

Comment: transform: scale(1.5);  is creating problem for you,

Comment: click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nn0au5a9/) for the JSFiddle

Comment: Ill try removing the scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resizing is because of your first rule `transform: scale(1.5);`. It tells the browser to initially resize the `.product` element to 50% more than its original size. But than on hover, you overwrite your `transform`- rule by only a rotation statement. Either delete this first rule or also use it in your `:hover` definition:

```
.product:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5) rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transform: scale(1.5);` created the problem!
Thanks to @Mohd Asim Suhail for pointing it out!

> transform: scale(1.5); is creating problem for you, – Mohd Asim Suhail 3 mins ago